# Multiprocessing in Python performing parallel writes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to do a task in parallel. It is a basic task and I am just trying to explore multiprocessing in python. I have 35 files, I am trying to do some file formatting on those 35 files and write them to new files. I have written the below code :

```
import csv
import json
import os 
import multiprocessing as mp

path = '<somepath>'

total_csv_file_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path+'csv_3'):
    total_csv_file_list.append(os.path.join(path+'csv_3',filename))
print(total_csv_file_list)    

def run_sed (path):
    path_csv=str(path)+'csv_3'
    path_json=str(path)+'json'
    for filename in path:
#       print("sed '1s/^/[/;$!s/$/,/;$s/$/]/' "+ (filename)+'>'+(filename.split('.')[0]+'.json'))
        os.system("sed '1s/^/[/;$!s/$/,/;$s/$/]/' "+ (filename)+'>'+(filename.split('.')[0]+'.json'))

#run_sed(total_csv_file_list)
p = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
total_file_list = p.map(run_sed,total_csv_file_list)
p.close()
p.join()
```

I have printed out the sed command before implementing the multiprocessing and it is getting formed correctly and is running as well when i try to run it from my shell. But when i implement it through the above code I am getting the below error :

```
sed: can't read r: No such file or directory
sed: can't read A: No such file or directory
sed: can't read i: No such file or directory
sed: can't read k: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: also it would be better if you used multithreading as that is more suited for I/O bound work, which is exactly your use-case here

Comment: Did you mean `for filename in os.listdir(path):`?

Comment: @aws_apprentice. It's more suited to network I/O, not disk I/O, which doesn't parallelize well with conventional hdds.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I'd say it depends. On my system with 96 GB, a lot of disk activity can be cached.

Comment: @ThomasWeller. For reading, maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `path` is a string, then `for filename in path:` will run over each character of the string.

Note that the list of file name that you pass in this line

```
p.map(run_sed,total_csv_file_list)
```

will already be separated into single file names by the `map()` function, so there's no need to loop over it again.

Concrete action: in `def run_sed (path):` get rid of the whole line `for filename in path:`

Comment: Hi Thomas can you please be a bit more elaborate @ThomasWeller

Comment: So, are you saying that in my function i should get rid of the loop. Path basically a list , containing the list of files to be processed

Comment: @user5149390: `total_csv_file_list` is a list, but `path` is not a list any more. It's one of the items out of `total_csv_file_list`.

Comment: yes. Got it. Thanks. I removed the loop and modified my code. It went through just fine. Thanks for your help again @Thomas Weller

Comment: Will it be possible to check how many files the code has processed, I was trying to process 35 files, only 28 files got processed. Will it be possible to capture the unprocessed files @Thomas Weller

Comment: @user5149390: There's no reason from Python point of view that they won't be processed. But look at `os.system()` again. Is it possible that the file names contain spaces and thus the `sed` command does not work reliably?